# How can I access a non-static member in a static event handler?

Tags: c#, static-members, process-exit

I already know you can't normally do this but here's my situation:

I have a non-static `List<T>` that gets added to during normal use, and then dumped to a database at an interval. I want to be able to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` in order to dump any values in my `List<T>` that haven't been dumped yet. The `List` is cleared each time it is dumped.

Is there any way I can access this `List` without the given context even though it is static -> not-static?

Comment: [No](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211137/why-can-static-methods-only-use-static-data). But if you can get access to the instance variables then you can access the data. Ultimately everything is within some context and with the right designs, methods, and APIs you can do what you are trying.

Comment: Make the handler non-static.

Comment: @SLaks or make the list static.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your handler as a lambda, in a scope where it has access to your list.

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2"
};

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, theArgs) =>
{
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\mylist.txt", list);
};
```

One nice way would be to encapsulate this behaviour inside a subclass of `List<T>`.

```
public class MyReallyPersistentList<T> : List<T>
{
    public MyReallyPersistentList()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, args) => 
        {
            var items = this.Select(i => i?.ToString());
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\temp\mylist.txt", items);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: so i can set the handler for ProcessExit even though Application.Run() has already been executed?

Comment: You never mentioned Application.Run before. Is this a WinForms application? I don't see why it would matter though - you can add a ProcessExit handler any time before your process exits (obviously not after!!)

Comment: Well, whatever you are using, you are aiming to add the ProcessExit handler just after you create the list. As I say, encapsulating this logic inside a subclass of `List` is the easiest and safest (and most self-documenting) way to do it.